# Content Security Policy blocking images from installed plugins' popup info window, as they are from external domains - global fix?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-headers, content-security-policy

[image]

I have Content Security Policy added to my WordPress site via `Header set` in `.htaccess`, and just found if I am on the WordPress plugins admin page (/wp-admin/plugins.php), and click "View Details" for any given plugin, its images in its popup are blocked. They come from an all external domains, none of which are allowed in my CSP (although it's possible there could be some overlap from another item or site function, but most if not all are not).

Do I have to add the `url` to `img-src` in my CSP for every plugin's "View Details" popup window, or is there a way to use CSP to say "images from any now or future installed plugin's view details window are allowed to load"? I am assuming I have to add each manually, and add new ones if a new plugin is installed - but wanted to check around from others first!

Thanks

Comment: A CSP that would just go, "hey whatever any plugin/module/script installed in the future wants to do, is automatically fine by me", would be rather pointless to begin with. You should add the exceptions you need, when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as mentioned in a comment by @JacobPeattie, was to add the domains to my `.htaccess` file where I am setting the CSP Headers, (turns out *most* plugins' "View Details" link loads images from ps.w.org, which I just learned). A few other plugins loaded images from other domains, so I also added each of those domain(s) to my `.htaccess` as well. This looks like:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy: img-src 'self' https://ps.w.org/ https://updates.theme-fusion.com/wp-content/uploads/
```

And so on (I didn't list all the other domains, just one to show as example. Now all the plugins' "View Details" images load without error as they are listed in the CSP.